# AutoIt syntax highlighting

Tags: discussion, feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I was working on [an answer to *Is there a way to ping a Bluetooth device from Windows?*](https://superuser.com/questions/1584737/is-there-a-way-to-ping-a-bluetooth-device-from-windows/1622403#1622403).

And I was wondering why AutoIt syntax highlighting on Stack Exchange sites is so "poor".

I was searching for information, btw. I created a pull request to: https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/src/languages/autoit.js

But going to the issue...

**First question:** [Answered here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360395/autoit-syntax-highlighting#comment1202773_360395).

Using `lang-autoit`

```autoit
Func _BluetoothFindFirstRadio(ByRef $phRadio)
```

Using `lang-default`

```
Func _BluetoothFindFirstRadio(ByRef $phRadio)
```

Why do `func` and `_BluetoothFindFirstRadio` and `ByRef` use the same color ?

IMHO, here in this case it should use different colors in syntax highlighting, but I do not know how or if this could be improved.

**Feature Request**
Please add support for `lang-autoit`

**Second question:**

```autoit
;~ https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/140162-help-with-dllstruct-and-pointers/?tab=comments#comment-984341
```

Why is number `140162` colored as a number, and the next part of this line is colored differently, regardless of the fact that everything is in the comment line?

The same problem with comment line is in case of `lang-vb` like in the following exmaple:

```vb
` https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/140162-help-with-dllstruct-and-pointers/?tab=comments#comment-984341
```

At [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360433/915027) I put some effort for testing.

Comment: The canonical is *[What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)* (contains the most detailed information).

Comment: AutoIt is some dialect of [BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC). Is there a mapping from the AutoIt tag to some close relative, like [VB.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) (`lang-vbnet` or `lang-vb`)? (A possible workaronnd could be `lang-vb`.)

Comment: Do you have a reference for `lang-autoit` (that you used in the Super User question) being a valid identifier?

Comment: according to [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) and: [Supported Languages](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md) AutoIt is supported. AutoIt have similar syntax to VBA and VBS, but there are many differences.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q [here](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/master/src/languages/autoit.js) is current version of `lang-autoit` used on SE sites.

Comment: @MichałLipok We do not use all languages available in Highlight.js and do not have the AutoIt language loaded into our system at all. `lang-autoit` simply reverts to default and allows Highlight.js to guess at how to highlight.

Comment: A minute ago I edit my second question. An example for `lang-vb` was added. There is also problem with incorrect colors in comment line.

Comment: @animuson according to your reqeust question was already edited,

Comment: I reedit as I find that I must to specify directly `lang-default`. Now it looks like `lang-autoit` automaticaly reverts `lang-default` as you said.

Comment: Could you add support for `lang-autoit` ?

Comment: At [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360433/915027) I put some effort for testing.

Comment: As for Question1 I maked them as answered and at the same time I make a `Feature Request`

Comment: As for Question2: How we can improve Highlighting ?

Comment: Now I see `How do I report a bug or request a new language?` in this [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#how-do-i-report-a-bug-or-request-a-new-language) Will follow that.

Comment: @MichałLipok please do some research before writing such request. What are the (bandwith) costs of that language support and is that reasonable compared to the amount of questions that benefit from it.

Comment: Ok. I understand your resoning on my FeatureRequest. As to Question2 I make 2 comments [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#comment1203258_184108) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#comment1203265_184108) because after reading this Wiki I think this is the correct place to ask this question (posted there in commets), before I could take any further action on  https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues .